# Unable to use MongoDB from my C# console application

Tags: c#, mongodb

> Unable to connect to server localhost:27017: Command 'ping' failed: no > such cmd (response: { "errmsg" : "no such cmd", "ok" : 0.0 }).

---

This might be a basic stuff which I'm missing out here... Please help me out

The above is the exception which I'm getting...
Below is the code which I'm using (It's the sample demo given in the site)
Note: My database is running. I'm able to create and edit the database from command line.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;

namespace MongoDBTest
{
    public class Entity
    {
        public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = "mongodb://localhost/?safe=true";
            var server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
            var database = server.GetDatabase("test");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<Entity>("entities");

            var entity = new Entity { Name = "Tom" };
            collection.Insert(entity);
            var id = entity.Id;

            var query = Query.EQ("_id", id);
            entity = collection.FindOne(query);

            entity.Name = "Dick";
            collection.Save(entity);

            var update = Update.Set("Name", "Harry");
            collection.Update(query, update);

            collection.Remove(query);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you `ping` _localhost_ from your command prompt?

Comment: Yes. I can able to ping my localhost from command prompt. I'm able to work on the DB from command prompt.

Comment: And changing _localhost_ to _127.0.0.1_ in the connection string makes no difference?

Comment: I even tried that. The problem is not that my application is not pinging the MongoDB Server. Because I always get in the Server console saying:   "connection accepted from #address and in the next line I get as end connection #address"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the mongo shell can you run these commands:

```
> db.version()
2.2.0
> db.runCommand("ping")
{ "ok" : 1 }
>
```

This is to verify that you aren't using a version of the server so old that it doesn't have the ping command.

Comment: Thanks a lot Robert. I was running 1.1.0 version :) Was downloading the file late night and I think got the oldest version. Now it works perfectly fine....